# Build unity-settings-daemon in 16.04

Tags: unity, package-management, compiling

I'm trying to build the package `unity-settings-daemon` in 16.04.

I got the source code with

```
apt-get source unity-settings-daemon
apt-get install unity-settings-daemon-dev
apt-get build-deps unity-settings-daemon
```

I run

```
./autogen.sh (works)
make (fails)
```

`make` fails with the error `unity-settings-daemon-15.04.1+16.04.20160701/plugins/screensaver-proxy/gsd-screensaver-proxy-manager.c:271: undefined reference to gsd_idle_monitor_get_core`

In the file `gsd-idle-monitor.h` these two functions are defined though. I have no idea what's wrong, can someone help?

Comment: Why are you trying to build an already available package?

Comment: For info sake ubuntu would  use a configure similar to this `./configure --enable-systemd --disable-packagekit --enable-ibus --enable-fcitx LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,--warn-unresolved-symbols -Wl,--as-needed"` The LDFLAGS being more relevant to your issue, though if me & making some change to the existing package source I'd rebuild as a packages using Ubuntu debian folder & rules, ect.

Comment: Thanks @doug wanted to change a few things on the source code, to test things. Your command worked. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it